# Zend Application - a 404 error instead of Zend_Acl_Exception - how?

Tags: zend-framework, http-status-code-404

At the present, when I type a wrong address I get the following:

```
exception 'Zend_Acl_Exception' with message 'Resource 'default_asda' not found' in /home/alkimi/www/ ...
```

I would like to, instead of this, display a costumized 404.

How can we configure the framework for doing so?

Thanks a lot,
MEM

Answer (score 2):

You get that exception when you attempt to query your ACL for a non-existant resource. You should check your ACL for the resource before calling `isAllowed`, eg

```
if (!$acl->has($resource)) {
    // do something that triggers or leads to a 404
}
```

Comment: Brown: Thanks. Thank you give me a start.

Comment: If I do this here: bootstrap.php:

$frontController->throwExceptions(FALSE); I get 404 instead of exceptions. This could be useful for production environments.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if action and controller exists (is dispatchable) before checking permissions:

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
if (!$front->getDispatcher()->isDispatchable($request)) {
    throw new Zend_Exception('Page not found', 404);
    return false;
}
```